# SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, http, ssl

I have developed an application using Codeigniter and PostgreSQL as the database.

Codeigniter application resides on IP `192.168.X.34` => Application server

PostgreSQL server resides on IP `192.168.X.35` => Database server

I frequently get below error in the production environment but in my local-pc I don't get any errors as such. Both production and local-pc are running ubuntu.

[image]

How can I fix this?

## Update

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

PostgreSQL version 9.1/main

There are no errors shown in the log file.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? OpenSSL version? What's in the PostgreSQL server logs?

Comment: Hm. For something like that Pg should be showing "client unexpectedly closed the connection", "could not receive data from client", etc. Try enabling `log_connections` and `log_disconnections`.

Comment: is it okay if I turn ssl=off in postgresql.conf. is it a bad practice? is it must to have ssl to on? Given that I have read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: If you're connecting purely on a trusted network where snooping of IP traffic isn't a concern then you can just turn SSL off, sure. It'd be a better idea to figure out why this is happening in the first place though. Your OpenSSL is too new for this to be the ssl renegotiation bug.

Comment: if you can please tell me a way to debug this, so I can identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the Apache at application server. Possible reason might be that Apache is using mixed connection to the database as in my case this was happening when I switched my databse server.

Comment: what do you mean by mixed connections to database?